# Setting boolean field with method return

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style, rules, conditional-statements

I have this code :

```
if (something.equals(something1)) {
   myObj.setBoolean(true);
} else {
   myObj.setBoolean(false); 
}
```

Is there any reason to write above code instead of just :

```
myObj.setBoolean(something.equals(something1));
```

Comment: Every time I see code like your first example I assume the author was either a complete novice or was coding under the influence.

Comment: @Laurence: ...or expecting the code to be maintained by a novice in the future.

Comment: @Fredrik: That sort of code isn't really any different from this sort of comment: `a = b + c; // a is b plus c`. These things make sense in the first couple of chapters of an introduction to programming book, but nowhere else. More verbose is not necessarily more readable, and I'd argue that in this case the more verbose form is actually *less* readable for anyone with any degree of programming experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a technical perspective: no. From a human perspective: maybe; it could make the code more readable and easier to follow.

I am not very knowledgeable when it comes to what kinds of optimizations that is performed by various compilers, but in theory it could be that the `if-else` block is effectively translated into the shorter version, since they are logically the same.

Comment: That depends. If `setBoolean` throws an exception, then they would be distinguishable by line number, if line numbers were available.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that it's easy to set breakpoints on the former.

However, the former contains a redundancy that is displeasing and carries a tiny risk of divergence.

Most debuggers support breakpoints conditional on value. This alternative supports breaking on true or false, without the redundancy.

```
boolean isEqual = something.equals( something1);
myObj.setBoolean( isEqual );
```